# axios get response is undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to populate a vuebootstrap table with users from the server.
I made the api call like this:

```js
export function getUsers() {
  const a = request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/users/',
    method: 'get'
  })
  console.log('getUsers request: ', a)
  return a 
}
```

I wrapped it in a const just to debug.

The output on console is:

```
getUsers request:  Promise {<pending>}
```

Inside the promise I get, among other things,

```
users:  (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}...,
```

So the call is indeed working.
In the script of the table (where I need these data to be displayed) I did:

```
import { getUsers } from '@/api/user'
data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      fields: [ 'utente', 'email', 'stato', 'iscritto_il', 'ultimo_accesso', 'operazioni' ]
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchUsers()
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchUsers() {
      await getUsers().then((response) => this.users = response.results)

      .catch((error) => console.log('ERROR: ', error.message))

      console.log('users: ', this.users)
      console.log('response: ', this.response)
    },
```

The output on the console:

```
users:  (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},..., __ob__: Observer]
index.vue:57 response:  undefined
```

In the template I did:

```html
<div>
    <app-container title="Lista utenti" />
      <b-table
        :items="users"
        :fields="fields"
        class="mx-2 py-1 tbl-user-list"
      >
      <template 
        v-for="(user, index) in users"
        slot-scope="row"
      >
        {{ row.user.username }}
        {{ row.user.email }}
        {{ row.user.is_active }}
        {{ row.user.date_joined }}
        {{ row.user.last_login }}
      </template>
      <template slot="operazioni">
        <b-button-group class="my-1">
          <b-button variant="success" class="p-2" @click="vediAttivita">Vedi Attività</b-button>
          <b-button variant="info" class="p-2" @click="vediProfilo">Vedi Profilo</b-button>
          <b-button variant="warning" class="px-2 mr-1 py-1" @click="modificaProfilo">Modifica Profilo</b-button>
        </b-button-group>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
```

The weird thing is, only the email got displayed (and the operations template, if that matters), but nothing else. How can it be is getting the emails (but, if I console.log them it gets undefined too)?

Thanks to anyone who could give me some hints about this.

I checked everywhere on the web, I can see this is a common question, so it can be seen as a duplicate, but I tried all the solutions, and none of them worked for me. I tried response in any possible way, as well as data, I tried defining them before using them, but still it gets undefined.

I read that .then and async wait together shouldn't be used, but if I remove async wait I don't get users[] filled, I get:

```
users:  [__ob__: Observer]
```

Comment: you don't have a response property, so `this.repsonse` *is* undefined.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, seen the code, how do you think I can get `users:  (15) {...}...`, which is inside the Promise, inside the results object?Looking better, I actually get it, because `users:  (15) {...}...` is coming from the console log of the vue page, not from the api call. So the object users got there. Why then? Maybe has to do with the v-for not displaying correctly?

Comment: Add `async` before `getUsers` function, and add `await` before `request` inside that function.

Comment: @ambianBeing Your reasoning makes sense, but: if I console.log inside .then, users is not filled yet (it's the console.log "users from top .vue", " users from .vue" is right after the .catch) => see the ouput: `users from top .vue:  [__ob__: Observer]
index.vue:80 users from .vue:  (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]`. Also, as I said, I know I shouldn't use async await in a promise, but if I don't do that, again, users is not filled. @Daniyal Lukmanov I tried that, but it doesn't change anything, unfortunately. Thank you though

Comment: @fdR Simply use a `v-if` for the async users data in b-table. `<b-table :items="users" :fields="fields" v-if="users && user.length > 0"
      >

Comment: @ambianBeing This is the template I'm using:                                              `<b-table
        v-if="users && users.length > 0"
        :items="users"
        :fields="fields"
        class="mx-2 py-1 tbl-user-list"
      >
      <template 
        v-for="(user, index) in users"
        slot-scope="row"
      >
        {{ row.user.username }}
        {{ row.user.email }}
        {{ row.user.is_active }}
        {{ row.user.date_joined }}
        {{ row.user.last_login }}
      </template>`

Comment: @fdR yeah I updated the answer with **v-if** directive. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: @fdR Something caught to me, looking at the code again: my reasoning about `console.log` being outside `then()` is misleading. Since you have `await` before that its gonna wait until it resolves the promise & that is why you see an ouput at console. Deleting the prev comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed with vuejs properly rendering the table. 
What I did:

```
<b-table
     :fields="fields"
     :items="users"
     v-if="users && users.length > 0"
     class="mx-2 py-1 tbl-user-list"
     >
    <tbody> 
      <template slot="utente" slot-scope="data">{{ data.item.username }}</template>
      <template slot="stato" slot-scope="data">{{ data.item.is_active }}</template>
      <template slot="operazioni">
        <b-button-group class="my-1">
          <b-button
            variant="success"
            class="p-2"
            v-b-tooltip.hover title="Vedi attività utente"
            @click="vediAttivita"
          >
            <span class="svg-container">
              <svg-icon icon-class="eye-open" />
            </span>
          </b-button>
          <b-button
            variant="info"
            class="p-2"
            v-b-tooltip.hover title="Vedi profilo utente"
            @click="vediProfilo"
          >
            <span class="svg-container">
              <svg-icon icon-class="user" />
            </span>
          </b-button>
          <b-button
            variant="warning"
            class="px-2 mr-1 py-1"
            v-b-tooltip.hover title="Modifica profilo utente"
            @click="modificaProfilo"
          >
            <span class="svg-container">
              <svg-icon icon-class="edit" />
            </span>
          </b-button>
        </b-button-group>
      </template>
  </tbody>
```

In the script, I defined the fields differently. **Key is the field to use to get data and label is what to show.**

```
fields: [
  { key: 'username', label: 'utente' },
  { key: 'email', label: 'email'}
  { key: 'is_active', label: 'stato'}
  { key: 'date_joined', label: 'iscritto_il'}
  { key: 'last_login', label: 'ultimo_accesso'}
]
```

And that worked! The answer comes from vuejs forum, here the link: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/template-is-acting-weird-with-v-for-directive/71378/4
Thanks to anyone who took time to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `request` inside your function, then you should use `acync-await` or a callback function with promise:

```
export function getUsers() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     request({
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/users/',
      method: 'get'
     }, function(err, response, body) {
      if(err) {
      reject(err)
    }
    console.log("response: ", response)
    console.log("body: ", body)
    resolve(body)
  })
 })
}
```

And in your methods it should be like this:

```
async fetchUsers() {
      try {
          const result = await getUsers();
          this.users = result //or result.data
          console.log('users: ', this.users)
          console.log('response: ', result)
      } catch(err) {
          console.log(err)
      }
    },
```

Also since users data is going come via `async` request its better to wrap b-table with a `v-if`:

```
<b-table v-if="users && users.length > 0"
        :items="users"
        :fields="fields"
        class="mx-2 py-1 tbl-user-list"
      >
      <template 
        v-for="(user, index) in users"
        slot-scope="row"
      >
        {{ row.user.username }}
        {{ row.user.email }}
        {{ row.user.is_active }}
        {{ row.user.date_joined }}
        {{ row.user.last_login }}
      </template>
      <template slot="operazioni">
        <b-button-group class="my-1">
          <b-button variant="success" class="p-2" @click="vediAttivita">Vedi Attività</b-button>
          <b-button variant="info" class="p-2" @click="vediProfilo">Vedi Profilo</b-button>
          <b-button variant="warning" class="px-2 mr-1 py-1" @click="modificaProfilo">Modifica Profilo</b-button>
        </b-button-group>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

Comment: I tried your code (just copy-pasted it, should I have changed something else?) and didn't work. This is the output: `users:  {__ob__: Observer}
index.vue:79 response:  {__ob__: Observer}
vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, Function, got Object`. If I put `this.users=result.data` everything gets undefined, not runtime error.

Comment: What is the output in the console for result?

Comment: An empty object `result from vue:  {__ob__: Observer}`

Comment: What do you mean? I have users array filled in the vue file, so I would guess I am, but maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: That's why, at this point, I'm starting to look at the v-for, even if that seems correct to me. Maybe it is just a problem of having them displayed in the table. ?

Comment: I've changed the `getUsers` function. Try that way.

Comment: It is wrong. It gets red underlined by the editor. Plus, resolve, err and response are declared but never used. I tried changing their position, but it is overall wrong. Thank you for your time, @Daniyal

Comment: :( not for me, table is totally empty, and the console too. How is  that??

Comment: @fdR I've added `body` to callback. Maybe that would be the server response. Try that.

Comment: Nope, but thanks again for your help. I think my code was working just fine (in terms of getting data through the api call and 'bringing' them to the vue page). It should be a problem with the vue.js template  or the v-if directive. As soon as I solve it, I'll post what was the issue.Thanks again.